# How to obtain the number of documents greater than a percentile aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

Here an ElasticSearch DSL query to return the value of the 90th percentile of a field named duration (duration is a webservice time response duration in milisecond but we do not care ...)

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "percentile90": {
      "percentiles": {
        "field": "duration",
        "percents": [
          90
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to calculate the number of documents for which the duration value is greater than the 90th percentile duration value.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use two requests? Easy with two requests, hard if not impossible with one.

Comment: Yes, I need to do that with one request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is something similar to HAVING clause in SQL. This is not supported by ElasticSearch (2.X AFAIK). You have to do it with two requests.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to calculate the number of documents for which the duration
>   value is greater than the 90th percentile duration value.

Isn't this 10% of the total number of documents, just based on the definition of percentiles? This is, assuming that durations are floats and thus could be expected to be unique.

On the other hand if you want to calculate for example average duration of those which took longer than 90th percentile you'd indeed need to use two queries.